# Get page content with "login with google" authentication using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, google-signin

I am wondering if it's generally possible. I have to get content of some page with specific URL utilizing python3.x. When I put URL into the browser, I have only one option: "Continue with google". I give my google account credentials and then desired page appears. I need his content. Is it possible to do it with python?

Comment: I think people talk about using selenium to do this? I don't remember - there was a running joke on the ProgrammingHumor subreddit: this guy would edit his code to reflect the highest upvoted comment and said he'd run it, so everyone was writing code to get security tokens and what not to make a post to SO or something like that.

Comment: By using the requests library it allows you to send HTTP requests via Python.

Answer (score 8):

Your Python app needs to ask for authentication and authorization to Google's API through the [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) protocol, which is a "*a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol*" that uses *bearer* tokens, and Google being in this case the *identity provider*.

Once the user had been signed-in to Google through your app, then the third-party app will *trust* the bearer tokens from Google, and will automatically consider the user signed-in.

The [process](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#server-flow) is quite articulated (it includes security measures etc), but basically it's the same for every OIDC-based system, i.e. eventually you'll get:

- an [ID token](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/#What-Is-an-ID-Token), which proves your authentication
- an [access token](https://auth0.com/blog/id-token-access-token-what-is-the-difference/#What-Is-an-Access-Token), which authorizes your app to access resources on your behalf

You can find ready-to-use Python snippets on the Google's [reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect).

I would avoid other automated ways, in this case.

Comment: I don't see the ready-to-use Python snippets. Theoretically, I understand what should happen. The Q was: how to do it in python. Can you please attach some samples?

Comment: @YuriLevinsky the samples are in the reference link.  Here is one for [Python](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#python)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) or other WebDriver based technology. It allows you to spawn and programmatically control a real browser. That have lots of advantages but you likely have to analyze a messy HTML in order to extract the content you need.

@Jonathan Ciapetti approach might be (much) simpler and robust in your case. Get OpenID credentials, then query the page or hit the API your need instead of trying to mimic human interactions. But if the page is so complex that only a real browser can display it (and there is no API available), use a real browser controlled by Selenium.

Selenium have Python bindings, WebDriver is a JSON based W3C API specification that Selenium wrap.